# String To DateTime Error while copying not null date in SQL Server in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to copy data from a CSV to SQL Server. While writing the data I am changing the schema for a column (Source Date (string) --> Target date (date)) in mapping. There is no empty(null) value in the column. I am getting the error:

> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.Core.TypeConversionException,Message=Exception occurred when converting value '24/01/2024' for column name 'EXPORT_DATE' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'DateTime' (precision:255, scale:255). Additional info: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,'

Input file looks like:
[image]

I already tried setting the dateformat as `dd/MM/yyyy`, `ddMMyyyy`, `dd-MM-yyyy` under the mapping section but it still shows the same error.
And the output schema in SQL Server side looks:

```
ID (varchar,null)
TYPE(varchar,null)
TO_DATE(date,null)
FROM_DATE(date,null)
Work(float,null)
EXPORT_DATE(date,null)
```

Comment: So what about the error is unclear and do you need help with?

Comment: `24/01/2024` is an ambiguous date format. Does it mean the 24th day of the first month, or the first day of the 24th month? The second interpretation would result in an invalid date. You are being told by the system that it considers `24/01/2024` to be an invalid date. You might deduce from this that the system is using the second interpretation. You can either tell the system to use a different interpretation, or transform the incoming string to an unambiguous format, like `yyyyMMdd`. I would do the transform in ADF, because that's exactly the sort of thing ADF is for.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I agree with @[allmhuran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7165279/allmhuran) that the above error is due to the date format of your input data.

You need to convert your input date format into the correct format which the sink table supports. So, use dataflow for this transformation. First check whether your source and target datasets support dataflow or not. If not use Blob storage as intermediate between your datasets.

In dataflow, give your source and use `derivedColumn` transformation. The dataflow also gives `null` when we use `date` functions on this string. So, use string operations for this. Here, for sample I am converting the input data to `yyyy-MM-dd` format. You can convert it to other formats like `yyyyMMdd` as per your requirement.

```
concat(split(mydate,'/')[3],'-',split(mydate,'/')[2],'-',split(mydate,'/')[1])
```

[image]

Add your SQL table as sink and execute it from pipeline.

**Here's the expected result:**

[image]